# classical producer consumer threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

In the [Classical producer consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). producer sleeps when `itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE` amd wakes up again when it goes down. But once `itemCount` grows up, producer thread is put to sleep. how can it know that `itemCount` has gone down and it needs to `wakeup` ?

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo-code the producer is something like:

```
void producer_thread()
{
    while(true)
        queue.push( produce() );
}
```

so consider the queue push method (I've used pthreads here, but the same logic applies with other libraries)

```
void SynchronizedQueue::push(Item const &i)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // queue is full, so wait for consumer
    while (queue.size() == BUFFER_SIZE)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);

    // when we get here, the queue has space
    this->queue.push_back(i);

    // make sure we wake a sleeping consumer
    if (queue.size() == 1)
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

and the pop method used by the consumer:

```
Item SynchronizedQueue::pop()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // wait for something to do
    while (queue.size() == 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);

    // if we get here, we have some work
    Item tmp = queue.front();

    // make sure we wake a sleeping producer
    if (queue.size() == BUFFER_SIZE)
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition)

    queue.pop_front();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: How are you defining the `condition` ?

Comment: As Nawaz says, this is the standard usage of a condition variable. So,  in this code, it would be declared as `pthread_cond_t condition`. I could implement exactly the same logic with C++11's `std::condition_variable` and `std::unique_lock` instead, though; it's the logic described in the _Using Monitors_ section of your linked wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional variables.

A typical usage of conditional variable is this:

```
//lock the mutex first!
scoped_lock myLock(myMutex); 

//wait till a condition is met
myConditionalVariable.wait(myLock, CheckCondition);

//Execute this code only if the condition is met
```

where`CheckCondition` is a function (or functor) which checks the condition (**as to when to wake up**, for example). It is called by `wait()` function internally when it *spuriously* wakes up and if the condition has not met yet, the `wait()` function sleeps again. Before going to sleep, `wait()` releases the mutex, *atomically*.

---

If your compiler supports `std::conditional` introduced by C++11, then you can see this for detail:

- [std::condition_variable (C++11 threads)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

If your compiler doesn't support it, and you work with win32 threads, then see this:

- [Condition Variables (Win32 threads)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx)

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903(v=vs.85).aspx) is a complete example.

And if you work with POSIX threads, then see this:

- [Condition Variables (POSIX threads)](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables)

---

You can see my implementation of `conditional_variable` using win32 primitives here:

- [Implementation of concurrent blocking queue for producer-consumer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12052/implementation-of-concurrent-blocking-queue-for-producer-consumer)

Scroll down and see it's implementation first, then see the usage in the concurrent queue implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to know - the OS will wake it up when a consumers signals.  In the P-C queue code, the producer will make a wait() call on some OS synchronization primitive.  This call will not return until a consumer thread makes space and signals the OS synchro object, (unless your faulty OS 'supports' spurious wakeups),  at which point the waiting producer thread will be made ready and, if there is an available core,  run immedaitely - the wait() call will return.

Traditionally, P-C queues are constructed from a simple non-thread-safe queue, a mutex to protect its indexes/pointers and two semaphores - one initialized to 0 to count items in the queue and one initialized to [queue size] to count empty spaces.  The producer waits on the 'emptySpace' and, when it gets a signal, locks the mutex, enqueues an object, locks the mutex and signals 'itemCount'.  The consumer waits on 'itemCount' and, when it gets a signal, locks the mutex, dequeues an object, locks the mutex and signals 'emptySpace'.